# How to count the words of a ms word 97-2003 doc file with c++?

Tags: c++, com, ms-word, word-count

I have just leant a bit of COM, and I know that the VBA programming is based on COM component provided by MS. But I do not now know how to programming office with c++, because I do not know how to import type library or something for my c++ programme. Here is my code to count the words of a doc file, but failed, could you help me to correct it, thanks.

```
#include <objbase.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlconv.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ole32.lib")
//0002095C-0000-0000-C000-000000000046

IID IID_Words = { 0x0002095C, 0x0000, 0x0000, {0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x46} }
//#import "msword.olb" how???
IDispatch* GetWordsInterface(LPCWSTR wszFileName);

int main()
{
    IDispatch *pDisp = NULL;
    LPOLESTR pwszFuncName = L"Count";
    DISPID dispID;
    HRESULT hr;

    pDisp = GetWordsInterface(L"D:\\test.doc");
    assert( pDisp != NULL );

    hr = pDisp->GetIDsOfNames( IID_NULL, &pwszFuncName, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dispID );
    assert( hr == S_OK );

    VARIANT result;
    hr = pDisp->Invoke(
            dispID, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET,
            NULL, &result, NULL, NULL);
    assert( hr == S_OK );

    printf("the count of words is %ld \n", result.dblVal);

    return 0;
}

IDispatch* GetWordsInterface(LPCWSTR pwszFileName)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_FALSE;
    IBindCtx *pbc = NULL;
    IMoniker *pMk = NULL;
    LPWSTR strClsid = NULL;
    LPWSTR strDisplayName = NULL;
    IUnknown *pUnk = NULL;
    IDispatch *pWords = NULL;
    CLSID clsid;

    hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    assert( hr == S_OK );

    hr = CreateBindCtx( 0, &pbc );
    assert( pbc != NULL &&  hr == S_OK );

    hr = CreateFileMoniker(pwszFileName, &pMk);
    assert( hr == S_OK && pMk != NULL );

    hr = pMk->GetClassID(&clsid);
    assert( hr == S_OK );
    StringFromCLSID(clsid, &strClsid);
    wprintf(L"CLSID : %s\n", strClsid);
    CoTaskMemFree(strClsid);

    hr = pMk->GetDisplayName(pbc, NULL, &strDisplayName);
    assert( hr == S_OK && strDisplayName != NULL );
    CW2A ascii(strDisplayName);
    printf("Display Name : %s\n", ascii);
    //wprintf(L"Display Name : %s\n", strDisplayName);
    CoTaskMemFree(strDisplayName);

    hr = pMk->BindToObject(pbc, NULL, IID_IUnknown, (void**)&pUnk);
    assert( hr == S_OK && pUnk != NULL );


    hr = pUnk->QueryInterface(IID_Words, (void**)&pWords); // FAILED HERE
    assert( hr == S_OK && pWords != NULL );

    pUnk->Release();
    pMk->Release();
    return pWords;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct version, the orginal version failed because the Document object does not support Words interface, but I manage to get the Words interface pointer through Document._Document(interface) Words(property).

```
// excelmoniker.cpp : 
//
#include "stdafx.h"

//0002095C-0000-0000-C000-000000000046
IID IID_Words = { 0x0002095C, 0x0000, 0x0000, {0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x46} };
//_DocumentInterface
IID IID_innerDocument = { 0x0002096B, 0x0000, 0x0000, {0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x46} };
IDispatch* GetWordsInterface(LPCWSTR wszFileName);
IDispatch* SubGetWordsInterface(IDispatch *pDoc);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    IDispatch *pWords = NULL;
    LPOLESTR pwszFuncName = L"Count";
    DISPID dispID;
    HRESULT hr;
    DISPPARAMS dispParams = { NULL, NULL, 0, 0 };
    VARIANT result;

    hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    assert( hr == S_OK );

    pWords = GetWordsInterface(L"D:\\test.doc");
    assert( pWords != NULL );

    hr = pWords->GetIDsOfNames( IID_NULL, &pwszFuncName, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dispID );
    assert( hr == S_OK );

    hr = pWords->Invoke(
        dispID, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET,
        &dispParams, &result, NULL, NULL);
    assert( hr == S_OK );

    printf("the count of words is %ld \n", result.dblVal);

    assert( pWords->Release() == 0 );

    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}

IDispatch* GetWordsInterface(LPCWSTR pwszFileName)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_FALSE;
    IBindCtx *pbc = NULL;
    IMoniker *pMk = NULL;
    LPWSTR strClsid = NULL;
    LPWSTR strDisplayName = NULL;
    IDispatch *pDoc = NULL;
    IDispatch *pWords = NULL;
    CLSID clsid;


    hr = CreateBindCtx( 0, &pbc );
    assert( pbc != NULL &&  hr == S_OK );

    //Test for the clsid for the doc
    hr = GetClassFile(pwszFileName, &clsid);
    assert( hr == S_OK );
    StringFromCLSID(clsid, &strClsid);
    wprintf(L"associated file CLSID : %s\n", strClsid);
    CoTaskMemFree(strClsid);

    hr = CreateFileMoniker(pwszFileName, &pMk);
    assert( hr == S_OK && pMk != NULL );

    hr = pMk->GetClassID(&clsid);
    assert( hr == S_OK );
    StringFromCLSID(clsid, &strClsid);
    wprintf(L"CLSID : %s\n", strClsid);
    CoTaskMemFree(strClsid);

    hr = pMk->GetDisplayName(pbc, NULL, &strDisplayName);
    assert( hr == S_OK && strDisplayName != NULL );
    CW2A ascii(strDisplayName);
    printf("Display Name : %s\n", ascii);
    //wprintf(L"Display Name : %s\n", strDisplayName);
    CoTaskMemFree(strDisplayName);

    //Get _Document Interface pointer
    hr = pMk->BindToObject(pbc, NULL, IID_innerDocument, (void**)&pDoc);
    assert( hr == S_OK && pDoc != NULL );

    //Get _Words interface pointer
    pWords = SubGetWordsInterface(pDoc);

    assert( pMk->Release() == 0 );
    assert( pDoc->Release() == 0 );
    assert( pbc->Release() == 0 );

    return pWords;
}

IDispatch* SubGetWordsInterface(IDispatch* pDoc)
{
    LPOLESTR pwszFuncName = L"Words";
    DISPID dispID;
    HRESULT hr;
    DISPPARAMS dispParams = { NULL, NULL, 0, 0 };
    VARIANT result;

    memset(&result, 0, sizeof(VARIANT));

    hr = pDoc->GetIDsOfNames( IID_NULL, &pwszFuncName, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dispID );
    assert( hr == S_OK );

    hr = pDoc->Invoke( dispID, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &dispParams, &result, NULL, NULL);
    assert( hr == S_OK && result.vt == VT_DISPATCH && result.ppdispVal != NULL );

    return (IDispatch*)result.ppdispVal;
}
```